# Vertically adjusting wrapped divs using jquery toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a set of divs that are being built dynamically and could include several rows of content. We are restricting the output to three columns per row. Using jquery toggle to toggle some content within the div, I am attempting to move the each of the divs below (in a vertical manner) to allow for room of reading the toggled element. I have attempted this using the following markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".trigger").click(function () {
        var trigger = $(this);
        $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle();

    });
</script>
<div id="toggleContainer">
    <div>
        <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 1</h3> 
        <ul class="toggle">
            <li>Line One</li>
            <li>Line Two</li>
            <li>Line Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 2</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">
            <li>Line One</li>
            <li>Line Two</li>
            <li>Line Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 3</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">
            <li>Line One</li>
            <li>Line Two</li>
            <li>Line Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 4</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">
            <li>Line One</li>
            <li>Line Two</li>
            <li>Line Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 5</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">
            <li>Line One</li>
            <li>Line Two</li>
            <li>Line Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 6</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">
            <li>Line One</li>
            <li>Line Two</li>
            <li>Line Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 7</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">
            <li>Line One</li>
            <li>Line Two</li>
            <li>Line Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 8</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">
            <li>Line One</li>
            <li>Line Two</li>
            <li>Line Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 9</h3>

        <ul class="toggle">
            <li>Line One</li>
            <li>Line Two</li>
            <li>Line Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, demonstrated in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sdj565s/ZnYPW/) fiddle

This is moving each of the elements below to the right to allow for viewing of the toggled content. My question is: how can I move the content down into the next row without moving the rows to the right? Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

> A1 A2 A3
>
> B1 B2 B3
>
> C1 C2 C3

and on click of A1, the state of B1 and C1 would be:

> A1       A2 A3
>
> A1toggle B2 B3
>
> B1       C2 C3
>
> C1

Answer (score 0):

if you want to overlap the content on to the next row, you can `position:absolute` the class toggle and increase the `z-index` accordingly

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity. I am hoping to move the affected columns down rather than to the right. Is that even possible? I had played with the position:absolute adjustment on the toggle list, but it then overlaps the content below (what I'm trying to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

You may simply consider the way you are arraging your content. You can arrange them vertically instead of horizontally so you have something like this :

```js
$(".trigger").click(function() {
  var trigger = $(this);
  $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle();

});
```

```css
div#toggleContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

div.content {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggleContainer">
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 1</h3>
    <ul class="toggle">
      <li>Line One</li>
      <li>Line Two</li>
      <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 4</h3>

    <ul class="toggle">
      <li>Line One</li>
      <li>Line Two</li>
      <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 7</h3>

    <ul class="toggle">
      <li>Line One</li>
      <li>Line Two</li>
      <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 2</h3>

    <ul class="toggle">
      <li>Line One</li>
      <li>Line Two</li>
      <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 5</h3>

    <ul class="toggle">
      <li>Line One</li>
      <li>Line Two</li>
      <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 8</h3>

    <ul class="toggle">
      <li>Line One</li>
      <li>Line Two</li>
      <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 3</h3>

    <ul class="toggle">
      <li>Line One</li>
      <li>Line Two</li>
      <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 6</h3>

    <ul class="toggle">
      <li>Line One</li>
      <li>Line Two</li>
      <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="trigger">Trigger 9</h3>

    <ul class="toggle">
      <li>Line One</li>
      <li>Line Two</li>
      <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also used `flex` in order to better arrange the elements.